# perform 2 transactions in same block in truffle

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to perform 2 transactions in the same block in truffle. Is that possible?

example

```
await pool.deposit(0, '0', { from: user1Address });
await pool.deposit(0, '0', { from: user2Address });
await pool.deposit(0, '0', { from: user3Address });
```

`pool` being a contract. I'd like to perform these transactions in the same block.

Comment: Can you explain why

Comment: I have logic that uses block number, it's annoying to have to increment it every single transaction

Comment: Is this testnet or mainnet? Because you do not have control in which blocks transactions are included.